# What are the alternatives to Behat for Python?

Tags: python, selenium, behat

I have an script in Python to test login on a web page.
My question : What are the alternatives to Behat compatible with Python?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found BEHAVE, and its working fine.
https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Yes, `behave` is THE tool for Python!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This question got heavily edited after I answered so I am copying my out of scope comment into the answer: "It seems popular enough => github.com/behave/behave"

Behat is a PHP library written in PHP. It would be too hard to get it to interface with your tests in Python.

On the other hand, I suggest looking up a Python-native BDD framework.

Comment: Thanks Alp for your help

Comment: @FlutterLover: here try this out. It seems popular enough => https://github.com/behave/behave